# Application Start Method exception - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I would like to say that I have looked a lot in the SO and none of the posts helped me, so I am asking again...

I'm trying to make a login screen, but I still get the same exception. My directory structure looks like this: [check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgF52.png)

My code looks like this:

```
    public class main extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/loginScene.fxml"));
          //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../login/login.fxml"));
          //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
          //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("src/relativepath//login/login.fxml"));
          //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/home/somepath/src/relativepath/login/login.fxml"));
          //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/loginScene.fxml"));

            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

This is the exception I get:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at br.com.fulltime.fullcam.mosaicoDesktop.main.Main.start(Main.java:12)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
```

Everything I've read so far has said "That's why FXML can not find the controller!", So I checked and it's really all right. Here is the controler statement:

```
fx:controller="br.com.mycompany.myproduct.module.login.controllerLogin">
```

I think this information can be requested:

- Java version: 8 (Oracle)
- IDE: IntelliJ Community
- GUI made in GluonHQ SceneBuilder.

  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgF52.png)

Comment: "Location is not set" means that Java cannot find your FXML file. Check the path again.

Comment: I did not understand the downvote, I already said that nothing helped me and I researched so much ...

Comment: Try just `/base_package/login/login.fxml`. Pass a full path to your loader.

Comment: I tried all those shapes and it still did not work. Even if I put the entire path of the file, it does not work. The curious thing is that I put it pretty much the same way into a test project and it worked ...

Comment: Show us your entire project structure then, because I guarantee the problem is with that path.

Comment: @Zephyr, I've updated the link of the image and put the line "Parent root ..." as it is now. The IDE can access the image using the path, but I still have the same exception.

Comment: There's the problem. Your FXML is in a resources package. I am not familiar with that structure, but I know you can't access it the same way you're trying to.

Comment: So I put it in the "login" package and nothing has changed :/

Comment: If you moved it to the `login` package, it looks like `/br/com/the/stuf/you/got/marked/out/login/controllerLogin.fxml` should work.

Comment: @Sedrick I've tried this, but not work :/ (Should be the view, not controller!)

Comment: Check out the `Github` link from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx) answer. Look closely at the project structure and `ContactApp.java`.

Comment: @Sedrick This was one of the answers I consulted, I understood well but I still do not know why I'm in trouble ...

Comment: In your image, you have the FXML file under `src/main/resources/fxml`. You should use `getClass().getResource("/fxml/sceneLogin.fxml")`.

Comment: You didn't follow the example well. I don't see where he has a resource folder in the example. I also see that he has all the `FXML`  in the same package with its `Controller`. So somewhere you went astray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you're getting a NPE. Try to debug, then, you can try this:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/loginScene.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple ways to do this. I prefer method 1, since it seems more straightforward to me.

To load a resource you need to know the path. The controllers know their own path, so I use them.

For instance, if I have a heirarchy of `java/hypnic/jerk/controllers/` with a `MainController.java` file in it, and I want to load an FXML file that will use this java file as its controller, I put it in `resources/hypnic/jerk/controllers/`. Then, when I call `FXMLLoader.load();` I do it this way:

```
FXMLLoader.load(MainController.class.getResource("mainScreen.fxml"));
```

From what I understand and how I see it, this tells the loader to use the path set forth by `MainController` and grab the `mainScreen.fxml` file from the path there.

This is, in my opinion, the easiest way to do it since it forces you to keep naming conventions AND you know where each `FXML` file is for the associated controller file.

You can also use pathing to find it, in your case, your `loginScene.fxml` is in the `fxml/` folder, so from `Main` I would do

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../../../../fxml/loginScene.fxml"));
```

The `../` means, go up one directory/folder. So depending on how may items you have blacked out, remember each `.` is a new folder in that name, you need to add a `../` until you are back to the `java` folder.

Lets use your example with a path of `java/br/com/one/two/three/main/`. Since your code is saying `getClass().getResource("fxml/loginScene.fxml")` you are looking for that file in the `resources/br/com/one/two/three/fxml/` folder. The path is based off the calling class `Main.java`, so it can't find it because the path in `resources`  doesn't exist.

So you need to back out of those dirs by using `../` until you get to it. each `../` represents another tier up. So in this case, if I did my math correctly, you would need 5 `../` in order to find the `fxml/loginScene.fxml` file. So the end result would be

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../../../../../fxml/loginScene.fxml"));
```

Now remember this is just an explanation and you will have to adapt it on your own.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Hm... I see. So, the "FXMLLoader.load" should be placed on "main" ?